# PHP array vs [ ] in method and variable declaration

Tags: php, standards

I have a question about PHP syntax.

When defining functions and variables, which convention should I use?

I know they do the same thing in practice but I would like to know which method conforms to best practice standards.

**Variables**

```
public $varname = array();
```

or

```
public $varname = [];
```

**Methods**

```
public function foo($bar = array()){}
```

or

```
public function foo($bar = []){}
```

Comment: Expect the code to be ran on php version < 5.4? use `array()` otherwise pick one and be consistent. There is no official standard.

Comment: That said, if you are using a framework (and you probably should be), then follow whatever practice the framework uses

Comment: Thanks, I am using cakphp 3.0 with some zend mixed in. CakePHP seems to be mixing it up a bit and have not investigated zend. Will never deploy on anything beneath 5.4. Think [] helps with legibility since it gives a distinction between method and array braces.

Comment: I prefer square brackets as well, as its consistent with many other languages. As i said, as long as you are consistent yourself you will be fine

Answer (score 96, accepted):

[PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) and [PSR-12](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-12-extended-coding-style-guide.md) (by [PHP Framework Interoperability Group](http://www.php-fig.org/)) do not mention short array syntax. But as you can see in [chapter 4.3](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#43-methods) they use short array syntax to set the default value of `$arg3` to be an empty array.

So for PHP >= 5.4 the short array syntax seems to be the de-facto standard. Only use `array()`, if you want your script to run on PHP <5.4.

Answer (score 33):

from PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

if you'd try using '[]' notation in earlier version than 5.4, it will fail, and PHP will throw a `syntax error`

for backward-compatibility you should use `array()` syntax.

Comment: Not downvoted, but i dont see how this answers the question at all

Comment: I think it answers the question, trying to use '[]' notation in a version prior to 5.4 is out of the question and is impossible.

Comment: The question asks "which convention should I use", and the answer is "you should use array() to preserve backward compatibility". How is it irrelevant?

Answer (score 10):

just made a test to see how [] performs vs array() here is what I got

```
testing 1 million []s ( with $arr[] = [] )
started at : 1561298821.8754
ended at: 1561298822.6881
difference: 0.81266021728516 seconds 

testing 1 million array()s ( with array_push( $arr, array()) )
started at : 1561298822.6881
ended at: 1561298823.843
difference: 1.1549289226532 seconds 

testing 1 million []s ( again while the processor is hotter)
started at : 1561298823.8431
ended at: 1561298824.7448
difference: 0.9017219543457 seconds
```

so [] performed about 20% faster

Comment: but you are performing a different operation (set to empty array vs array_push), so it's not apples to apples

Comment: $arr[] = [] and array_push( $arr, array()) performs the same operation, appends an empty array to an array (doesn't set array to an empty array) , the people who upvoted your post are most likely newbies

Comment: oh, now that you explain what it does, it actually makes sense, except it seems pointless appending an empty array as the next element

Comment: Upvoted OP's comment, due to fallacy of the first comment. Still I would argue it's the same apples being compared. Perhaps a better approach would be to compare `$arr[] = []` and `$arr[] = array()`. And if you wish also (separately) `$arr[] = []` and `array_push( $arr, [] )`.

Comment: Actually tested it and have dug into it. And indeed [] is a lot faster. And that's because [] is now what PHP deems as the primary operator. array() gets translated to [] first and then executed.

Comment: @Alex Could you explain where can I see proof that array() gets translated to [] so that I can present this reasoning to other people?

Answer (score 7):

That depends on what version of PHP you are targeting. For the best backward compatibility, I'd recommend you to use array(). If you don't care about older versions (< PHP 5.4), I'd recommend you to use a shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

it's obvious that new PHP projects should use [] because it's shorter, cleaner and similar to other languages like JS.