# recommendation PHP for array()

Tags: php

Do you know if it's better to use PHP array() or []

I know that [] is the short version of array() but I can not know the PHP recommendations ?

What is the best way to do following PHP ?

Thank you !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Makes no difference in the outcome, depends on your preference of which is more readable, I prefer `[]` but there is no right or wrong.

Comment: `array();` works in most php versions.

Comment: Depends whether you need to provide backward compatibility for older (no longer supported) versions of PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array vs \[ \] in method and variable declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651996/php-array-vs-in-method-and-variable-declaration)

Answer (score 4):

both are same the only difference is 
  [ ] is supported in PHP >= 5.4:

```
['id' => 'id', 'name' => 'name']
```

This is a short syntax only and in PHP < 5.4 it won't work.