# Looking to return an array in a method php

Tags: php

I have this little bit of code and I want to return an array of strings after looping through the array and pushing the `$id` parameter to the array.

```
function getAdminEmail($id) {
    $query = executeQuery("SELECT email FROM system_users WHERE access='" . $id . "'");
    $emails = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($emails,$row['email']);
    }

    return $emails;
}
```

Comment: first use `$emails = []` instead of `$emails = array();` due to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651996/) . did you try `array_push($emails,$row['email']);` and what's the result of this code? I think I didn't understand what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAdminEmail($id) {
    $query = executeQuery("SELECT email FROM system_users WHERE access='" . $id . "'");

    return $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Will return the results of the query in an associative array.

Also, look into using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating the `$id` in the string like that.