# PHP- [] and array() while declaring a variable

Tags: php

I want to know if there is a difference, and what is the difference between declaring a variable as [] and as array()

i.e

Difference between `$p=[]` and `$p=array()`

Comment: Have you checked out the language documentation at php.net?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651996/php-array-vs-in-method-and-variable-declaration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP array vs \[ \] in method and variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651996/php-array-vs-in-method-and-variable-declaration)

Answer (score 4):

The difference being the array() is for versions 5.4 and below, whereas [] can be used in versions 5.4 and above.
The [] array is quicker than using array() as well.