# Is resetting a PHP array by assigning false to it incorrect?

Tags: php, arrays, reset

I have read [Best way to clear a PHP array's values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261925/best-way-to-clear-a-php-arrays-values) and nobody suggested

```
$array = false;
```

I have used it in my code to recycle an array and it seems to work fine.

Are there any reasons why it shouldn't be used?

Comment: You can try `$array = array();`, This will allow user to avoid warnings for all array related function performed with your array variable. Hence I hope this is the best method

Comment: you mean, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961839/7611062) is said by no one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to clear a PHP array's values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261925/best-way-to-clear-a-php-arrays-values)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean false not null.

Comment: @MarkOverton He has already shared that link in Question.

Comment: I mean it won't reset the array, it will just change the datatype to a boolean with value false

Comment: @Ajith that does not answer my question.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Comment: `$array = [];`. You now have an empty array. Best not to type juggle, why would an array be false (boolean)?

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks, yes it's now empty and the code works. Any reason I shouldn't be using it?

Comment: its just good practice to not type juggle, and to be more strict. for instance `5 == '5'` is true, but `5 === '5'` is false

Comment: @DaveWhite "Are there any reasons why it shouldn't be used?" mainly because you no longer have an array in that variable, you have a boolean instead. So if you then pass this variable to any other code which is expecting to be able to do array-like operations on it, you'll have problems. PHP is loosely-typed, but that doesn't mean you should change the types of your variables arbitrarily. If you want an empty array then create an empty array, not a boolean.