# How can I remove all data in an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to delete all the data in this array. I'm beginer

```
$data = array(
      ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Alex'],
      ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Max'],
      ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'George']
  );
```

I'm using this code to do it, but it doesn't work :(

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
     unset($item);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why `$data = [];` is not a solution for you?

Comment: What do you mean by removing all the data from the array?

Comment: Could be a dupe?  Why the laravel tag?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/10261925/3392762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to clear the complete array, why not using `unset($data)`?
Your code does not work they way as you expect it, because in your loop you are defining a new variable `$item`. You are then unsetting this variable `$item` which has no effect on original the values of your `$data` array.
If you want to use a loop you need to define it like that:

```
foreach ($data as $index => $item) {
    unset($data[$index]);
}
```

This clears all values from `$data` but not unsetting the `$data` array itself.
A more efficient way compared to the loop would be to just assign a empty array to `$data` like:

```
$data = [];
```