# ZF2- Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' (PHP 5.5.12)

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

I am working on a zend framework 2 application, and I am working with port 8080. My main probleme in the begining is that i couldn't retrieve or add data from database in the views (probably, a probleme with connection with database). It didn't show any error, but data couldn't be retrieved or added.
I tried to specify the port in global.php:

```
<?php

return array(
  'db' => array(
             'driver' => 'Pdo',
             'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=pizza;host=localhost', 
             'driver_options' => array(
                 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES\'UTF8\''
                 ),
              ),
  'service_manager' => array( 
      'factories' => array(
          'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
          )
      ),
 );
```

After that, I got this error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
```

I looked for a solution, and I found one. I commented a line in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

It solved the probleme, but now Im stuck with another probleme:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in C:\wamp\www\pizza\config\autoload\global.php on line 18
```

I found some suggestions on how to fix this probleme by Linux command:

```
 apt-get install php5-mysql /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But i want a solution for windows 7, or any other you may find useful. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: if you replace it with the representing integer 1002 does it work? Also i do not see the port specified in your global.php. I think you get that error because you comented that line in php.ini

Comment: the port=8080 is specified, and like a said if  i uncomment the line the "MySQL server has gone away" error occcurs. could you please tell me what should i replace with 1002

Comment: then i suggest you to solve "MySQL server has gone away" error and consider this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232150/pdo-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems like you found bad advice on two occasions. You're getting the `Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'` error because by commenting out `php_pdo_mysql.dll` you effectively disabled the MySQL extension. So uncomment that line - you definitely want that there.

You mentioned that you're "working with port 8080" but it's not clear if your ZF2 application is running on port 8080, or if you're running MySQL on that port (which would be non-standard). You said you tried to specify this port in your `global.php` configuration file, but the port is nowhere to be seen in the configuration you posted.

The "MySQL server has gone away" error means the MySQL connection is timing out. Usually this is caused by PHP scripts that run for a very long time (>30 seconds) without touching the DB connection. This is unlikely to happen in a standard web application, so we'd need more info about what led up to this error in order to help you.

You also said that you "couldn't retrieve or add data from database in the views". If this is still the case, there must be an error somewhere, even if it's not being shown to you. So check the relevant error logs and your error settings.

Comment: Can you tell me what info you need

Comment: If you re-enable MySQL, what errors do you get (if any) when you try and retrieve or add data from the database? If you get a blank screen or no error, what error(s) appear in the error logs?