# How I can automatically reopen persistent connection with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have workers that works on php (yii2) under supervisord.

I using persistant connection for MySQL DB.

```
'attributes'=>[
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
]
```

But it refused after 8 hours.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away.
```

I think that it already was realised.

**How I can automatically reopen persistent connection?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO: MySQL server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232150/pdo-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: I had the same problem, and in the end I'm not using persistent connections - the worker connects, does it's job, then disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

**I have done this way:**

```
try {
    ...
} catch (...) {
    Yii::$app->db->close();
    Yii::$app->db->open();
    ...
}
```