# GCP MySQL server has gone away (Google SQL MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

We are running on Google Compute Engine/Debian9/PHP/Lumen/Doctrine2 <-> Google SQL MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7.

Usually it works without hiccups, but we are now getting error messages, similar to the one below, with increasing frequency:

> *Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=123456*
>
> *PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away*

Any idea why this is happening and how i would fix it?

Comment: Please see this question and its answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232150/pdo-mysql-server-has-gone-away. If this is not your case, give us more details. Also look at this list of possible causes for that _MySQL server has gone away_ message: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Did you solve the issue with the links provided? Please confirm

Comment: We have changed the server to high availability and seems that it's resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html), there is a list of cases which may be causing this error. A few are:

> - You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the
>     MYSQL structure is equal to 0).
> - You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large...An INSERT or REPLACE statement that
>     inserts a great many rows can also cause these sorts of errors.
>
> . . .

Please refer to the link for a complete list.

Also, there see this answers on the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232150/pdo-mysql-server-has-gone-away).