# MySQL has gone away too often

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine along with Cloud SQL.
My application cannot connect to MySQL about 35% of requests.
PHP throws error: `MySQL server has gone away`

After SQL restart it works well for few minutes, then same thing again.
If I connect from hosts other than App Engine then connection is fine.

What is going on here? My business halted completely because of it.

Comment: I have seen the same issue on other platforms and resolved it by putting my connect inside a `for (i =0; i<3; i++)` loop. Usually it succeeds on the second attempt. You can also potentially resolve it by turning off persistent connections.

Comment: Try to check this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857403/gcp-mysql-server-has-gone-away-google-sql-mysql-2nd-gen-5-7 ] that has a similar issue and let us know if the solutions offered helped you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled persistent connections and it works now.