# Can't imoprt to mysql database exported from a yii project

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've been assigned to create a new feature in one of our apps. The app was developed by someone who left and we don't have a contact for.

The project is was writen in yii2. I have never used yii. I usually work with nodejs and vuejs. I know some php, but yii is just very complex. (by looking at it)

Anyway, I copied it to my machine with ftp, and exported the database. But I can't import it into my local machines mysql.
The error i'm getting:

> #2006 - MySQL server has gone away
>   Warning in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#261
>   Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=19844

Which I never seen before. Now I don't know if this has anything to do with yii or not. The app works just fine on the servers.

Thanks for the help an advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO: MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232150/pdo-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: Here is a link to the error screenshot, maybe that helps https://drive.google.com/open?id=19sR7uRyvny7MsMVsGacKwl1Uz2jn3nJR

Comment: this error is not related .. to Yii  .. is just a MySqli error ..

Comment: Did you read the suggested duplicate and the links that answer suggested?

Comment: Yes I read it. Didn't really seemed like my case. The database is not too big only like 20 tables. Nor can be the admin blocking it. Checked the dns server, that's fine too. But I did get a somewhat different error. Unknown keyword (near "ON" at position 25)

Comment: Also  found this under functions https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xERBRtfl2ESw2CazVnnVeACSpqIAkyhv

Comment: How do you importing this database? This error seems to be unrelated to Yii.

Comment: simply in mysql. I did it since. I imported it, it failed then i deselected what was imported and tried again until i had the whole thing. So not really solved..